# how to remove first two words of a strings output

Tags: linux, bash, awk, sed, cut

I want to remove the first two words that come up in my output string. this string is also within another string.

What I have:

```
for servers in `ls /data/field`    
do    
  string=`cat /data/field/$servers/time`
```

This sends this text:

```
00:00 down server
```

I would like to remove "00:00 down" so that it only displays "server".

I have tried using `cut -d ' ' -f2- $string` which ends up just removing directories that the command searches.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Please, do the things properly :

```
for servers in /data/field/*; do
    string=$(cut -d" "  -f3- /data/field/$servers/time)
    echo "$string"
done
```

- backticks are deprecated in 2014 in favor of the form `$( )`
- don't parse `ls` output, use `glob` instead like I do with `data/field/*`

Check http://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashFAQ for various subjects

Comment: I must admit, I have the same bad habit, so I went about looking for the reason why one shouldn't use ls in this situation.  So thanks for that link +1.  Anyways, the FAQ is rather large, so to save everyone else some time, why you shouldn't use ls, see:  http://mywiki.wooledge.org/ParsingLs

Answer (score 6):

Use `-d` option to set the delimtier to space

```
$ echo 00:00 down server | cut -d" "  -f3-
server
```

**Note** Use the field number `3` as the count starts from `1` and not `0`

From man page

```
  -d, --delimiter=DELIM
              use DELIM instead of TAB for field delimiter

   N-     from N'th byte, character or field, to end of line
```

**More Tests**

```
$ echo 00:00 down server hello world| cut -d" "  -f3-
server hello world
```

The `for` loop is capable of iterating through the files using globbing. So I would write something like

```
for servers in /data/field*
do    
  string=`cut -d" "  -f3- /data/field/$servers/time`
...
...
```

Comment: This works as long as the words are delimited by exactly _one_ space.

Answer (score 2):

You can use sed as well:

```
sed 's/^.* * //'
```

Answer (score 0):

For the examples given, I prefer cut. But for the general problem expressed by the question, the answers above have minor short-comings. For instance, when you don't know how many spaces are between the words (cut), or whether they start with a space or not (cut,sed), or cannot be easily used in a pipeline (shell for-loop). Here's a perl example that is fast, efficient, and not too hard to remember:

```
 | perl -pe 's/^\s*(\S+\s+){2}//'
```

Perl's `-p` operates like sed's. That is, it gobbles input one line at a time, like `-n`, and after dong work, prints the line again. The `-e` starts the command-line-based script. The script is simply a one-line substitute `s///` expression; substitute matching regular expressions on the left hand side with the string on the right-hand side. In this case, the right-hand side is empty, so we're just cutting out the expression found on the left-hand side.

The regular expression, particular to Perl (and all PLRE derivatives, like those in Python and Ruby and Javascript), uses `\s` to match whitespace, and `\S` to match non-whitespace. So the combination of `\S+\s+` matches a word followed by its whitespace. We group that sub-expression together with `(...)` and then tell sed to match exactly 2 of those in a row with the `{m,n}` expression, where n is optional and m is 2. The leading `\s*` means trim leading whitespace.